# Studying linear algebra with "Linear algebra done right" without any linear algebra background?

Tags: reference-request

I started reading " Linear algebra done right" and I'm really enjoying the book. The thing is that most people say it's intended for a second linear algebra course.

Is it a bad idea to learn from the book? Should I read a first course book (Would love a recommendation for a book if so).

PS: I'm attending uni in October as an undergraduate math major, So the emphasis on abstraction and proofs is really important for me. (And also this is the way i find the most fun learning mathematics).

Thanks.

Comment: If you understand what you're reading and can do the exercises stick with it. When you get to uni talk with an advisor about whether you should take linear algebra or skip it. I suspect they'll advise the former.

Comment: Linear algebra is a bit of a Swiss Army knife of techniques that get used across the mathematical landscape.  The first book you study will definitely not be the last, but it will help build up intuitions that will serve you well in most of your math courses.

Answer (score 3):

I used this book for a second course in Linear Algebra and thought it was great.  If you are understanding and enjoying it, then I do not see a reason why you would want to pick up a typical first course book.  Most first course books will emphasize computation and it can become boring quickly, but since you said that you enjoy learning through proofs then I think you should stick with your current book.  Good luck in your future math endeavors.